# Java Send Mail error when changed the from maill

Tags: java, email

I want to send a mail from java program, i used the below code to send mail. added mail id's and credentials(username,password) in the code. My problem with this code is i can send the mail to any mail id but if i change the from mailid,username,passwrod i am getting the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect.
I tried in C# i am getting the same type of error first used mail is working only.

```
 public class SendMailSSL {

         public static void main(String[] args) {  
             // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
              String to = "tomailid@gmail.com";//change accordingly

              // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
              String from = "frommail@gmail.com";
              final String username = "frommail";
              final String password = "frompassword";

                String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

              Properties props = new Properties();
              props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
              props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
              props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
              props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

              // Get the Session object.
              Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
              new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                 protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                 }
              });

              try {
                 // Create a default MimeMessage object.
                 Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

                 // Set From: header field of the header.
                 message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

                 // Set To: header field of the header.
                 message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                 InternetAddress.parse(to));

                 // Set Subject: header field
                 message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

                 // Now set the actual message
                 message.setText("Hello, this is sample for to check send "
                    + "email using JavaMailAPI ");

                 // Send message
                 Transport.send(message);

                 System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

              } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
              }

         }
    }
```

Comment: You need the from mail ID and corresponding credentials to send mail as that user.  If you want to use a different account to send mail, you'll need the corresponding credentials.

Comment: i am using my mail id as from mail to send a mail but i am getting the error.what i have placed in first time in the code is working fine without any errors.

Comment: Are you trying to send as a user for which you do not have the password?

Comment: @SrikanthE are the credentials you are using (while getting exception) correct? Did you try logging into that email account with the password you provided in the code?

Comment: @iMan i have successfully loggedin with that my two mail id credentials. but in code i can send mails from 1st mail only if i change the mail id username,password i am getting the erro

Comment: Only the first time given mail is working as sender if i change the sender i am getting error why ?

Comment: Check that `smtp` is enabled for seconf account.

Comment: How to check that, is smtp must enable for every account ?

Comment: not the second one i tried with one more mail with username and password but i am getting error i am able send from first mail with username and password only.how to solve this

Comment: The smtp settings works for one mail only not other mail id's why this happens.?